# how to overcome this anyone explain me .....my pc is 64bit and java version is 10.0.1 and jdk is 1.6.0_29

Tags: java, windows-10, 64-bit, java-6, java-10

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Helloworld : Unsupported major.minor version 54.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Could not find the main class: Helloworld.  Program will exit.

Comment: What do you mean by 'java version is 10.0.1 and JDK is 1.6'? What version of Java did you use the compile this code and what version are you using to run it? It looks like you compiled with Java 10 - you can't then run that code on Java 1.6

Comment: in cmd i typed javac -version then it displayed "javac 10.0.1"

Comment: and for java -version it showing java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode)